# creating a Mesos cluster considering nodes from different cloud platforms and network

Tags: cloud, mesos, mesosphere

I have a situation where i need to create a mesos cluster considering KVM based agent nodes from different cloud platforms.

I am trying to explain the situation here:

I have access to project A and project B. For project A, I have 6 KVM based nodes and for project B, I have 3 KVM based nodes. Each of the KVM nodes has a public ip associated with it. Now I need to create a Mesos cluster of three masters from project A cloud, then need to associate 6 agents to the cluster, 3 from project A and 3 from project B.

Problem That I have faced:

I was able to setup the mesos master and agents in the same cloud platform (network) with their internal ip (like 10.0.0.50) but in the zookeeper if I mention floating ip the cluster does not start working.Now without public ips I can not add agents from the different cloud account.

One straight question:
can we setup a Mesos master quorum of three nodes with their floating public ips instead of internal ip?

Please suggest what could be the best way to incorporate multiple agent nodes from different networks. FYI, I am using mesosphere based packages to install messos/marathon and zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue for single master and 3 agents resides in different networks.

- master public ip is: 129.11.22.33
- agent1 public ip is: 130.11.22.33
- agent1 public ip is: 135.11.22.33
- agent1 public ip is: 140.11.22.33

to start mesos master :

```
sudo ./bin/mesos-master.sh --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --advertise_ip=129.11.22.33
```

to start mesos aglent:

```
sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh master=129.11.22.33 --advertise_ip=130.11.22.33
sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh master=129.11.22.33 --advertise_ip=135.11.22.33
sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh master=129.11.22.33 --advertise_ip=140.11.22.33
```

You can see all three mesos agents appearing in the mesos web UI at

129.11.22.33:5050/slaves in the browser